# How to implement stack-like informations for a RoR model

Tags: database, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, stack

i need to add to an "Event" model some information about "sub-events". For example, the Event might be a Match and a sub-event can be a goal (I need to track the striker too, and the minute), substitution or other. How is the best method to implement this? I think that is not a good solution to create a new Model for a Goal, I want that all the informations stay inside the Match model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it can be done via "belongs to itself" association.

Look at this: [Rails 3 - A model with a one to one relationship to itself - do I need belongs_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749611/rails-3-a-model-with-a-one-to-one-relationship-to-itself-do-i-need-belongs-t)

The answer suggest using [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry), or simple belongs_to association:

belongs_to :event, :foreign_key => "parent_event_id"

Also, in your model, you should add "event_type" column and put 'match', 'goal', or whatever you want here.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it IS good solution to create `Goal` model, that would `belongs_to` a `Match` and a `Striker` and would store the information when it has happened (the minute).